# What is the effective method for selecting the keyframe

Tags: image, image-processing, video-processing

For the extraction of keyframes from a video I hesitate between two methods:

1/ Segment my video based on the value of the group of pictures (GOP) pictures, then look for the keyframes.

2/ Use a shot boundary detection technique to segment my video based on an efficient algorithm and then look for keyframes

Otherwise, with the use of the group of pictures (GOP) video segmentation, I will be sure to have an efficient segmentation or a shot detection algorithm must perform this step?

Comment: Are you talking about any specific codec with GOP? For example if it was H.264 codec (MP4), you could check the file bytes for the one's marked as keyframes and send those to the decoder t get the image. I'm not too familiar with other video codecs (like VP9 in webM) but I can advise about H.264 if that's what you're using.

Comment: @VC.One in other words, can we use boundary shoot detection algorithms to segment videos or in compressed H.264 domain videos are already segmented by the group of pictures (GOP) that starts with images I-Frame ?